# respect relationships when returning nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a collection of parent and child nodes like so:

```
(adult1:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child1:Person)
(adult1:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child2:Person)

(adult2:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child3:Person)
(adult2:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child4:Person)
```

When i do the following query, I get back the adult and child nodes with no respect to their relationships.

```
MATCH (parents:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(children:Person)

RETURN parents, children
```

I'd like to iterate over the parents and for each, return the parent and their direct children

**Record1**

```
- adult1
- child1
- child2
```

**Record2**

```
- adult2
- child3
- child4
```

I've spent a few hours at this and haven't nailed a solution yet.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can collect children nodes and add parent to the collection. Then, return it.

```
MATCH (parent:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(children:Person)
RETURN parent + collect(children)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return a collection of children per parent:

```
MATCH (parent:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child:Person)
RETURN parent, COLLECT(child) AS children;
```